# Easily edit formatlistpat?

Tags: vim

I'd like to try out different regexes for the `formatlistpat` option.  Any suggestions as to the easiest way to do this?

I know in Insert mode I can use `<Ctrl+r>` to paste in a register.  And that I can use this do edit macros.  Is there an equivalent for options? Or something even simpler?

The other idea I had was just sourcing a buffer with the set command in it.  But I'm unsure of the way to put an option value into buffer so it can be edited.

Any thoughts? Tips? Suggestions?

Comment: Uhmm, when you say different regexes, do you mean different regex format (Vim supports three, if I'm not mistaken; the differences are subtle, but there nevertheless) or you just want to try out some regexes to see whether they work.

I didn't quite get that about pasting, and what you want to paste where. Or the part with editing.

Comment: I'm completely fine using the regex format/syntax that the pattern is already in -- the one I'm familiar with from patterns associated with substitions.

To edit a macro, I can paste the register containing the macro into a buffer, edit it, then paste it back into the register.

I was hoping to just tweak the formatlistpat without messing it up.

In the mean time since asking the question, I've manually typed the value into a buffer in the form of the set command.  And I've been yanking the line and using :@= to run it repeatedly. That's worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are editing command-line you have two options here:

1. Use autocomplete:

   ```
   set formatlistpat=<Tab>
   ```

   (not really tab, but rather whatever 'wildchar'/'wildcharm' is set to). This will populate command-line with current option value, properly escaped. I cannot suggest this way for this particular option because double escaping looks ugly and there are lots of escapes in most patterns.
2. Use expression register (works both in command-line and in insert mode):

   ```
   let &formatlistpat=<C-r>=string(&formatlistpat)<CR>
   ```

   Note that in this case escaping is not done automatically. Using `:let` and `string()` is easier then do proper escaping for `:set`.

Comment: Awesome.  I've used <tab> to complete the option name but not the value.  That helps.  I forgot about both the &option syntax and expression register.  Very helpful! Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Based on [ZyX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158241/712526), the following is effective for a `.vimrc` file:

```
let &formatlistpat="^\s*\d\+[\]:.)}\t ]\s*\|^\s*[-*]\s+"
let &formatlistpat=string(&formatlistpat)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody still looking on how to best set the `formatlistpat` in the `.vimrc` without any ugly escaping:

```
let &formatlistpat='^\s*\[[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_]\+\]:\s*'
let &formatlistpat.='\|'
let &formatlistpat.='^\s*[-–+oо*•]\s\+'
```

The given example also has a neat trick on how to make the `formatlistpat` code more readable.